# Не получается установить Adafruit_DHT для проекта с датчиком температуры и влажности

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Делаю проект с датчикоим температуры и влажности DHT11
Когда запускаю код из проекта в терминале пишит:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp_sensor.py", line 12, in <module>
    import Adafruit_DHT
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Adafruit_DHT'
```

Пробовал установить через `pip install Adafruit_DHT`
Но снова ругается:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\andre\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-50ifv0yw\\Adafruit-DHT\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-50ifv0yw\\Adafruit-DHT\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-50ifv0yw\Adafruit-DHT\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-50ifv0yw\Adafruit-DHT\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-50ifv0yw\Adafruit-DHT\setup.py", line 49, in <module>
        platform = platform_detect.platform_detect()
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-50ifv0yw\Adafruit-DHT\Adafruit_DHT\platform_detect.py", line 40, in platform_detect
        pi = pi_version()
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-50ifv0yw\Adafruit-DHT\Adafruit_DHT\platform_detect.py", line 91, in pi_version
        with open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as infile:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/cpuinfo'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Что делать?

Comment: оффтоп, нужно использовать \`\`\` (три символа), а не \`\` для форматирования кода :)

Comment: Проверьте, что тот модуль поддерживает windows, а то ошибка намекает, что тот искал пусть как в линуксах: `Adafruit_DHT`

Comment: Основной вопрос - как вы собираетесь подключать этот датчик к обычному компьютеру?

Comment: Я буду подключать его к PocketBeagle

Comment: @Vecher, если так, то и библиотеку нужно устанавливать на PocketBeagle, а не на ваш обычный компьютер.

Comment: @inslolor Уже понял, как раз переделываю)